# Return the class of the parent node in javascript (not jquery)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to return the class of the parentnode of a selected element using Javascript. Here is what I have, but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
function pClass(){
  var pc = this.parentNode.className;
  return pc;
}
```

thanks.

Comment: You need to show how you've attached the listener and to which element.

Comment: You need to understand that *"but it's not working"* **is not helpful**. Why would you not specify what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It works like a charm. What's the issue?

```js
function pClass(){
  var pc = this.parentNode.className;
  console.log(pc);
  return pc;
}

const btn =  document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', pClass);
```

```html
<div class="parentFoo">
  <button type="button" id="btn">Click me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that `this` isn't an html element. What do you get when you do a `console.log(this);`? Below is an example of how you can achieve what you're after. If you can show us a little more code (namely, how you're using your `pClass` function), it would help give you code that's more tailored to what you're doing.

```js
const child = document.querySelector('#childDiv');
const parentClass = child.parentElement.className;
console.log(parentClass);
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <div id="childDiv"></>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be working becuase of the way you call `pClass()` - you did not show this in your code.

However, this method will work for you:

```
<div class="myClass">
    <div id="myDiv" onclick="getParentClass(this)">Click Me!</div>
</div>
```

```
function getParentClass(elem) {
    var pc = elem.parentNode.className;
    alert("Parent class: " + pc)
}
```